# Adding car bookings to car object from single SQL query with JOIN

Tags: java, jsp, ms-access, join

I'm writing a car rental application and I have two tables in my database, `Cars` and `Bookings`. Here are the fields for each:

```
Cars
CarID  |  Make  |  Model  |  Year

Bookings
BookingID  |  CarID  |  UserID  |  StartDate  |  EndDate  |  Paid
```

I'm writing a method called `getCars()` which returns an `ArrayList` of type `Car`. In my `Car` class, I have another `ArrayList` called `bookings`, which holds all the bookings for that car. I can insert the bookings in the constructor of `Car`, like so:

```
public Car(Integer carId, String make, String model, Integer year, ArrayList<Booking> bookings) {
    this.carId = carId;
    this.make = make;
    this.model = model;
    this.year = year;
    this.bookings = bookings;
}
```

However I'm having trouble getting the car and booking information from my database, and then constructing the correct `Car` object from the results. I'm trying this:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM Cars INNER JOIN Bookings ON Bookings.CarID = Cars.CarID";
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
results = pstmt.executeQuery();

ArrayList<Booking> bookings = new ArrayList<Booking>();

while(results.next()) {

    bookings.add(new Booking(
        results.getDate("StartDate"),
        results.getDate("EndDate"),
        results.getBoolean("Paid"),
        results.getString("HouseName"),
        results.getString("AddrFirstLine"),
        results.getString("AddrSecondLine"),
        results.getString("PostCode")
    ));

    cars.add(new Car(
        results.getInt("CarID"),
        results.getString("Make"),
        results.getString("Model"),
        results.getInt("Year"),
        bookings
    ));
}
```

It kind of works, but it produces duplicate results. If a car has two bookings, it will create two `Car` instances for the same car instead of one instance with multiple `Car.bookings`. It will also give each `Car` every booking in the database, like this:

[image: Screenshot]

How can I properly construct the `Car` objects in this case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that `cars` is a `List<Car>`. For your first problem, you have two solutions:

- replace `List<Car>` with `Map<Integer, Car>` and check if the car already exists before adding it to the map:

```
Integer carId = results.getInt("CarID");

if (!cars.containsKey(carId)) {
    cars.put(carId, new Car(...));
}
```

- replace `List<Car>` with `Set<Car>` and implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` in `Car`, so that the `Set` will not add a second `Car` if it already contains another `Car` that equals the one you are adding

For your second problem, I suggest you use a second `Map<Integer, List<Booking>>` which contains a list of bookings per `Car` id:

```
Map<Integer, List<Booking>> bookingsPerCar = ...;

// In your loop:
List<Booking> bookings = bookingsPerCar.get(results.getInt("CarID"));
if (bookings == null) {
    bookings = new ArrayList<>();
    bookingsPerCar.put(results.getInt("CarID"), bookings);
}

bookings.add(new Booking(...));
```

Comment: The solution using a Map would great, thanks. However, I still can't get bookings to add properly. I tried this code: http://pastebin.com/Nf0tVLi1 however now the web page displays "No cars found in database", so it must be going wrong somewhere. Could you take a look? Thanks.

Comment: The code seems to be correct, perhaps it's in the code that calls `getCars()`? Also, it seems you are not using `bookingsPerCar` after adding data to it, do you really need it?